# Laravel Count Checked Checkbox Real-Time

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Good Days Guys. How do I count the checked checkbox in real-time?
I have these button labeled **Transfer Students** and I want the user to know how many students are **currently checked** (since our classrooms are size sensitive)

```
  <button   
    wire:click="editModal()"
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-300 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded">
        Transfer Student($count of selected students) 
      </button>
```

---

```
 <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedStudents.{{ $stud->id }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would alter how you're tracking your `selectedStudents` to make things a little easier.

Your current implementation of `selectedStudents.{{ $stud->id }}` results in an array where the `key` is the `student id` and the `value` is either also the `student id` (when selected) or `false` when unselected. Selecting and then unselecting a checkbox does not remove the array element, instead its `value` is set to `false`.

So instead, if you bind Livewire to your `selectedStudents` array and then use the `value` attribute of the `input` element, you can achieve a similar but simplified result.

```
<input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedStudents" value="{{ $stud->id }}" />
```

The result of the above is a numerically indexed array where the `value` is the `student id`. When you select a checkbox, an element is added to `selectedStudents` and when you unselect a checkbox it is removed.

The benefit of this is that you can now simply use `count($selectedStudents)` to get the number of students selected.

```
{{ count($selectedStudents) }} have been selected
```